# Pass Less variable in to attribute selector

Tags: html, css, web, less

I have a task to write 100 styles for every of 10 columns in Less.
Code looks like this at the moment:

```
.loopingCellWidth (@index) when (@index > 0){
                    &[data-1-column-width="@{index}"] {
                        .exercise-table-row {
                            .exercise-table-row-part {
                                &:nth-child(1) {
                                    width: percentage(@index * 0.01) !important;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    &[data-2-column-width="@{index}"] {
                        .exercise-table-row {
                            .exercise-table-row-part {
                                &:nth-child(2) {
                                    width: percentage(@index * 0.01) !important;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                     // ..... up to 10
                    .loopingCellWidth(@index - 1);
                }
                .loopingCellWidth(100);
```

I would like to create a variable `@numberOfColumn` and place it in the attribute selector, like this:

```
&[data-@{@numberOfColumn}-column-width="@{index}"] {
```

But this solution doesn't work.
Any ideas how it should be done? Of course if it's even possible.

Comment: Have you tried with `&[data-#{@numberOfColumn}-column-width="#{index}"] {`?

Comment: No... never saw such thing

Comment: Could you try ?

Comment: @johannchopin I've got an error ```expected ']' got '#'
   error: expected ']' got '#'```